# Is this property of a sequence of random probabilities well-known?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, reference-request, random-variables

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, (\mathcal{F}_n)_n, P)$ be a probability space equipped with a filtration, and let $(P_n)_n$ be a sequence of random probabilities adapted to $(\mathcal{F}_n)_n$. By that I mean that $P_n: \mathcal{F} \times \Omega \to [0,1]$ is a probability measure on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ in its first argument and a $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable random variable in its second argument. Assume that $P_1(A, \omega) = P(A)$.

I'm wondering if the following property is well-known and if it has any interesting consequences:

> For all $n$, all $m > n$, ($P$-almost) all $\omega \in \Omega$, and all $A \in \mathcal{F}$, 
>   $$P_n(A, \omega) = \int P_m(A, \omega')P_n(d\omega', \omega).$$

It seems plausible to me, for instance, that this property could guarantee that $(P_n(A))_n$ has an almost sure limit for every $A$, but I haven't been able to prove it yet.

Mainly, I'm just wondering if this property has been studied, and if so, what a good reference is.

Comment: Are you sure that the expression above is right? Because $$P_{n+m}(A, \omega) = \int P_m(A, \omega')P_n(d\omega', \omega) $$ looks like the Chapman-Kolmogorov equation and is satisfied whenever $P_n$'s are the transition kernels associated to a Markov process. But your probability measures are themselves random (a sequence of random measures), so this may not help you much.

Comment: @Sayantan Thanks for commenting, but I’m not sure I understand what you’re getting at. I see that the equation I wrote is similar to the C-K equality. What lesson do you draw from this?

Comment: Well, I don't know the context your sequence of random probability measures arise from. So I was only saying that, since you have equations that look like C-K, it might help to look into the question of whether they have a connection with some Markov-type processes.

Comment: @Sayantan Oh, I see, thanks. There’s no relevant context I’m leaving out. It’s nothing more than an arbitrary sequence of random probabilities.

Answer (score 1):

I'll address a slightly different question, namely, about a similar family satisfying 
$$
P_n(A, \omega) = \int_\Omega P_m(A, \omega')P_n(d\omega', \omega) \tag{1}
$$
for all $A\in\mathcal F$, almost all $\omega\in \Omega$, and all $m\ge n$ (so I assume that the equality also holds for $m=n$).

I claim that in this case $P_n(A,\omega) = P(A\mid \mathcal G_n)$ for some $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal G_n$ such that $\mathcal G_n \subset \mathcal F_n\cap \mathcal G_{n+1}$.

For $X\in L^1(\Omega)$ define
$$
E_n X = \int_{\Omega} X(\omega')P_n(d\omega',\omega).
$$
Then $(1)$ is equivalent to:
$$
E_n E_m  = E_{n}, m\ge n. \tag{2}
$$
Also note that $E_1 X = E[X]$.

Setting $n=m$ in $(2)$, we get $E_n^2 = E_n$, so $E_n$ is a projection. Note also that $E_n$ is positive and
$$
E[|E_n X|]\le E[E_n |X|] = E_1 E_n |X| = E_1|X| = E[|X|],
$$
so $E_n$ is contractive in $L^1(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$. Finally, since $P_n$ is a probability measure, $E_n \mathbf{1} = \mathbf{1}$. Therefore, by Douglas' Theorem (Corollary 4 [here](https://msp.org/pjm/1965/15-2/pjm-v15-n2-p06-s.pdf)), there exists some $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal G_n$ such that $E_n X = E[X\mid \mathcal G_n]$. Owing to the assumption that $P_n$ is $\mathcal F_n$-measurable in the second argument, we have $\mathcal G_n\subset \mathcal F_n$. The fact that $\mathcal G_{n}\subset \mathcal G_{n+1}$ follows from $(2)$ applied to $m=n+1$.

Comment: Also, I just want to check, to show that (1) implies (2), does the "standard machine" argument work? I.e., the implication is clear for indicator functions, we use linearity for simple functions, and monotone convergence for non-negative integrable functions, and so on.

Comment: 1) Yes, exactly, the standard machine. 2) No clear idea for $m>n$.

Comment: I hope you don't mind if I continue to ask some follow-up questions. Can $\mathcal{G}_n$ be described more explicitly? Is it just $\sigma(P_n(A))$, for example?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: @aduh, no, it's not possible. By the last displayed formula, $E_n X$ is integrable. An integrable random variable can't be infinite with positive probabilty.

Comment: Okay, so everything is well-defined assuming (1). But without assuming (1) the way you defined $E_n$ may not be okay. Correct?

Comment: Correct! Unfortunately, I didn't answer the original question (and I don't have any fresh ideas).